# Getting Integer Value From a TextField

Tags: java, android, colors

I'm trying to take an RGB value (not hexadecimal, the actual constant value, such as  -16711936) from a textfield and display it in a new activity (to use it as an integer). I attempted to do this by converting the string to an integer, but it still ends up crashing the program. Here's the code:

FULL SOURCE:issue occurs in testvalue function

```
   package com.example.seniordesign;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity { //1

    //public final static String RGB_VALUE = "com.example.seniordesign.RGB_VALUE_USE";
    TextView pixelcord, rgbvals, rgbnumvals, red, green, blue, RGB; 
    ImageView iv;
    Button btn;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //2

        /* GATHER THE INFORMATION FROM THE LAYOUT TO ORGANIZE APP*/
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* SET ON CLICK LISTENER TO GET CLICK REPSONSE -- LAUNCH CAMERA AND TAKE PHOTO */
        /* SET VARIABLES FOR USE FROM EACH VIEW */
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView); /* USE IMAGE VIEW FIELD*/
        pixelcord = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pixelcord); /* USE TEXT FIELD FOR PIXEL */
        rgbvals = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rgbvals); /* USE TEXT FIELD FOR RGB VALUES*/
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takePhoto);
        /* SET INFORMATION OF WHAT TO DO UPON EACH CLIK*/
        iv.setOnTouchListener(imgSourceOnTouchListener);
        red = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.red);
        blue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.blue);
        green = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.green);
        RGB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RGB);


/* =====================================CAMERA BUTTON=====================================*/        
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //3

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) { //4

                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            } //*4


        }); //*3
/* =======================================================================================*/        


        } /* END OF ON CREATE*/ //*2

    /* DECLARATION OF IMG TOUCH FUNCTION*/

    OnTouchListener imgSourceOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() { //5

        @Override

        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) { //6


            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();
            float[] eventXY = new float[] { eventX, eventY};

            Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix(); 
            ((ImageView)view).getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);

            invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY); 
            int x = Integer.valueOf((int)eventXY[0]); /* POTENTIALLY REDUNDANT*/
            int y = Integer.valueOf((int)eventXY[1]);

            /* CHECK TO MAKE SURE VALUES ARE WITHIN BITMAP RANGE*/


            /* SET TEXT FUNCTION TO THE FIELD USING SET TEXT METHOD*/
            pixelcord.setText("X:" + String.valueOf(eventX) + "/ Y:" + String.valueOf(eventY) ); 

            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); 
            int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

            rgbvals.setText("Color Value" + "#" + Integer.toHexString(touchedRGB));
            rgbvals.setTextColor(touchedRGB);
            int rval = Color.red(touchedRGB);
            int bval = Color.blue(touchedRGB);
            int gval = Color.green(touchedRGB);
            red.setText(String.valueOf(rval));
            blue.setText(String.valueOf(bval));
            green.setText(String.valueOf(gval));
            RGB.setText(String.valueOf(touchedRGB));




            return true;

        } //*6


    }; //*5

    public void testvalue(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestValue.class);


        TextView RGBval = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RGB);
        int rgb_val_use = Integer.parseInt((String) RGBval.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("RGB_VALUE", (int)rgb_val_use); 
        startActivity(intent);


    } 

    @Override

    public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    { //7
        if(requestCode == 0)
        { //8
            Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);

        } //*8
    } //*7


} //*1
```

and here is my logCat:

```
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9089)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     ... 11 more
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'RGB' as integer
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:383)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:372)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     at com.example.seniordesign.MainActivity.testvalue(MainActivity.java:125)
10-31 07:27:44.334: E/AndroidRuntime(9915):     ... 14 more
```

Is it just a syntax error or am I going about this incorrectly? I appreciate the help

NOTE: The value in the textfield is techinically a string I guess, this is the code I used to place it in the field (touchedRGB is an integer value).

```
RGB.setText(String.valueOf(touchedRGB));
```

If it makes a difference, this is the XML from this particular section

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/RGB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/green"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/green"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/green"
        android:text="RGB" />
```

Comment: Try `int rgb_val_use = Integer.parseInt(RGBval.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("RGB_VALUE", rgb_val_use); `

Comment: is the value in textview an int value?

Comment: No, the value in textview is a string (displaying an integer). This is the code I used on the textview `RGB.setText(String.valueOf(touchedRGB));` where 'touchedRGB' is an integer

Comment: @SSS thanks for the suggestion, but the code is still crashing.

Comment: are you sure, you got the right TextView? And you are not just trying to convert your label? btw. variable identifiers should not start with a uppercase letter.

Comment: @Angelo.Hannes I'll add the XML so you can doublecheck me, but I'm pretty sure it's a TextView not just a label. And I will change the case, thank you!

Comment: how do you resolve your `RGB` before `RGB.setText(String.valueOf(touchedRGB));`? you set "RGB" as text in your layout. And as @aegean said, this can't be parsed as integer. So maybe it is the label, or your setText didn't work. But that is up to you to find out, or you post more code.

Comment: @Angelo.Hannes I will post the entire source

Comment: how and when do you call testvalue?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you have a string("RGB") in your textView. So you got a NumberFormatException.
Set an integet value in your textView and try again.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'RGB' as integer
```

Edit: Could you try code below?

```
public void testvalue(View view) {

    try{
        TextView RGBval = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RGB);
        String valueStoredInRGBvalTextView = RGBval.getText().toString();           
        int rgb_val_use = Integer.parseInt(valueStoredInRGBvalTextView);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestValue.class);
        intent.putExtra("RGB_VALUE", (int)rgb_val_use); 
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Not touched yet
    }
}
```

Edit2:
You are setting the integer touch value to RGB textView after first touch occurs. If you invoke your `testvalue` method before touching anywhere, you'll get this exception. Change your `testvalue` method as I wrote above. Your problem will be solved.

Comment: Ok, it says 10-31 08:14:26.341 E/AndroidRuntime(11362): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 08:14:26.341 E/AndroidRuntime(11362): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x must be >= 0

Comment: I'll run it again and check, one sec

Comment: I can't find that section in my log cat. If it makes a difference, I'm reading the log cat directly from my phone, not through an IDE (the sd card won't work when the phone is attached to the computer).

Comment: Ok, just waiting for emulator to fire up again.

Comment: Oddly enough, everything works on the emulator but it crashes when I run it on a phone.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying now. I'm displaying it as a string value, i need to display it as an integer value to use it

Comment: Point is, you are triying to parse a string value to integer. This is only possible if your string value is represantation of an integer. For example you can have "123" in your textView and you can parse it to integer. But if you have a text like "ABC" you'll have a NumberFormatException. Now, your problem occurs because you have a string as "RGB" in your textView and you get a NumberFormatException. Posible reason for this is you are not setting the integer touch value to your textView before triying to parse its value to integer. Or you are setting that touch value to a different textView.

Comment: Use my edited code and please read Edit2 comment. That'll be solved now.

Answer (score 0):

try this you cannot cast the int value to String like this -> (int)(rgb_val_use)

change it into   `new Integer.toString(rgb_val_use)`;

```
intent.putExtra("RGB_VALUE",new Integer.toString(rgb_val_use));
```

Comment: Tried it but the programming is still crashing. The value in the textfield is an integer, i used ' RGB.setText(String.valueOf(touchedRGB)); ' to set it where touchedRGB is an integer if that makes a difference.

Comment: touchedRGB's value seems 'RGB' at your crash.

Comment: @aegean Could you explain? When i run the code, I see numerical  values in that particular textfield before I press the test button (for instance like -16711936).

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer for it. Could you try that?

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer rgb = Integer.getInteger((String) RGBval.getText(), null);
if (rgb == null) {
    // input string is not integer
} else {
    // use rgb to start new activity
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My IDE tells me that parseInteger can't be used on integers :/ it won't compile